# Linux from Scratch 11.1 Systemd edition: ERROR: Dependency "mount" not found, tried pkgconfig

Tags: systemd, lfs

So when I tried to install systemd-250 with LFS 11.1 systemd edition, it threw an error. Not much I can give, except the logs, and the fact that when I typed in the 'mount' command in the LFS chroot, it says that it wasn't found... I am using the Ubuntu 20.04 CD image. Please help, I don't want to restart all of my progress. Also, I rebooted the ISO because of a seperate hang, then I remounted everything and set the $LFS variable and all of that. Here is the log:

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.61.1
Source dir: /sources/systemd-250
Build dir: /sources/systemd-250/build
Build type: native build
Project name: systemd
Project version: 250
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 11.2.0 "cc (GCC) 11.2.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.38
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program tools/add-git-hook.sh found: YES (/sources/systemd-250/tools/add-git-hook.sh)
Program tools/check-compilation.sh found: YES (/sources/systemd-250/tools/check-compilation.sh)
Program tools/meson-build.sh found: YES (/sources/systemd-250/tools/meson-build.sh)
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 11.2.0 "c++ (GCC) 11.2.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.38
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-format-signedness: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-parameter: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdate-time: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wendif-labels: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=format=2: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=implicit-function-declaration: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=int-conversion: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=overflow: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=override-init: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=return-type: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=shift-count-overflow: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=shift-overflow=2: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=undef: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wfloat-equal: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wlogical-op: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wredundant-decls: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-aliasing=2: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-function: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wwrite-strings: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-error=#warnings: NO 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-string-plus-int: NO 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-maybe-uninitialized: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-result: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=missing-declarations: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=missing-prototypes: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -fdiagnostics-show-option: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-strict-aliasing: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -fstack-protector: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -fstack-protector-strong: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -fvisibility=hidden: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments --param=ssp-buffer-size=4: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -ffunction-sections: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -fdata-sections: YES 
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,--fatal-warnings: YES 
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,-z,now: YES 
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,-z,relro: YES 
Compiler for C supports link arguments -fstack-protector: YES 
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,--warn-common: YES 
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,--gc-sections: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wzero-length-bounds: YES 
Checking if "-Werror=shadow with local shadowing" : compiles: YES 
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-format-signedness: YES 
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES 
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-parameter: YES 
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstringop-truncation: YES 
Checking for size of "dev_t" : 8
Checking for size of "ino_t" : 8
Checking for size of "time_t" : 8
Checking for size of "rlim_t" : 8
Checking for size of "typeof(((struct timex *)0)->freq)" : 8
Checking for size of "char16_t" : 2
Checking for size of "char32_t" : 4
Checking for size of "struct mount_attr" : 32
Checking for size of "struct statx" : 256
Checking for function "secure_getenv" : YES 
Checking for function "__secure_getenv" : NO 
Checking for function "memfd_create" : YES 
Checking for function "gettid" : YES 
Checking for function "pivot_root" : NO 
Checking for function "ioprio_get" : NO 
Checking for function "ioprio_set" : NO 
Checking for function "name_to_handle_at" : YES 
Checking for function "setns" : YES 
Checking for function "renameat2" : YES 
Checking for function "kcmp" : NO 
Checking for function "keyctl" : NO 
Checking for function "copy_file_range" : YES 
Checking for function "bpf" : NO 
Checking for function "statx" : YES 
Checking for function "explicit_bzero" : YES 
Checking for function "reallocarray" : YES 
Checking for function "set_mempolicy" : NO 
Checking for function "get_mempolicy" : NO 
Checking for function "pidfd_send_signal" : NO 
Checking for function "pidfd_open" : NO 
Checking for function "rt_sigqueueinfo" : NO 
Checking for function "mallinfo" : YES 
Checking for function "mallinfo2" : YES 
Checking for function "execveat" : YES 
Checking for function "close_range" : YES 
Checking for function "epoll_pwait2" : YES 
Checking for function "mount_setattr" : NO 
Checking for function "move_mount" : NO 
Checking for function "open_tree" : NO 
Checking for function "getdents64" : YES 
Checking for function "getrandom" : YES 
Program sh found: YES (/usr/bin/sh)
Program echo found: YES (/usr/bin/echo)
Program sed found: YES (/usr/bin/sed)
Program awk found: YES (/usr/bin/awk)
Program stat found: YES (/usr/bin/stat)
Program ln found: YES (/usr/bin/ln)
Program git found: NO
Program env found: YES (/usr/bin/env)
Program perl found: YES (/usr/bin/perl)
Program rsync found: NO
Program test/test-efi-create-disk.sh found: YES (/sources/systemd-250/test/test-efi-create-disk.sh)
Program quotaon /usr/sbin/quotaon /sbin/quotaon found: NO
Program quotacheck /usr/sbin/quotacheck /sbin/quotacheck found: NO
Program kmod found: YES (/usr/bin/kmod)
Program kexec /usr/sbin/kexec /sbin/kexec found: NO
Program sulogin /usr/sbin/sulogin /sbin/sulogin found: NO
Program mount /usr/sbin/mount /sbin/mount found: NO
Program umount /usr/sbin/umount /sbin/umount found: NO
Program loadkeys found: YES (/usr/bin/loadkeys)
Program setfont found: YES (/usr/bin/setfont)
Program nologin found: YES (/usr/sbin/nologin)
Program gperf found: YES (/usr/bin/gperf)
Message: gperf len type is size_t
Has header "sys/capability.h" : YES 
Has header "crypt.h" : YES 
Has header "linux/memfd.h" : YES 
Has header "linux/vm_sockets.h" : YES 
Has header "sys/auxv.h" : YES 
Has header "valgrind/memcheck.h" : NO 
Has header "valgrind/valgrind.h" : NO 
Has header "linux/time_types.h" : YES 
Has header "sys/sdt.h" : NO 
../meson.build:824: WARNING: 
The local user with the configured user name "nobody" of the nobody user does not have UID 65534 (it has 99).
Your build will result in an user table setup that is incompatible with the local system.
../meson.build:843: WARNING: 
The local group with the configured group name "nobody" of the nobody group does not have GID 65534 (it has 99).
Your build will result in an group table setup that is incompatible with the local system.
Program tools/choose-default-locale.sh found: YES (/sources/systemd-250/tools/choose-default-locale.sh)
Run-time dependency threads found: YES
Library rt found: YES
Library m found: YES
Library dl found: YES
Library crypt found: YES
Checking for function "crypt_ra" with dependency -lcrypt: NO 
Checking for function "crypt_preferred_method" with dependency -lcrypt: NO 
Checking for function "crypt_gensalt_ra" with dependency -lcrypt: NO 
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
Run-time dependency libcap found: YES 2.63
Did not find CMake 'cmake'
Found CMake: NO
Run-time dependency libbpf found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Program clang found: NO
Program llvm-strip found: NO
Program bpftool /usr/sbin/bpftool found: NO
Run-time dependency mount found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

../meson.build:1021:0: ERROR: Dependency "mount" not found, tried pkgconfig

A full log can be found at /sources/systemd-250/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

Comment: As the end of the log states, and you yourself have noted, `mount` is not found. Has it been installed? Is the path correct? Is `mount` in the path? You say that "... then I remounted everything" so it must be present in your system somewhere. Maybe it just isn't visible in the LFS chroot..? What does the full log at `/sources/systemd-250/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt` say? You haven't included the relevant parts of *that* particular log in your question. I am not familiar with LFS and have only recently been getting to grips with it, so I can't help from that angle.

Comment: When I remounted it, I was not in chroot.